# Jenkins - Multiple jobs for a single Project Issue

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, jenkins-pipeline

I am relatively new to Jenkins (using 2.32). So pardon my ignorance.

In my current setup, I have 2 free-style jobs for a single project - One point to production branch (*/master) and another to the Dev branch (*/dev). Bitbucket is configured to invoke (webhook) Jenkins on changes.

Once the dev is built and it passes all the unit test it gets deployed to Dev Server. Eventually, all dev changes are pushed to Master via pull request. The change in Master branch triggers the Master job and deploys the artifacts to productions.

I don't feel this setup is correct and would like you experts advise on this. Having 2 jobs makes me uncomfortable. What if I want a stage release? I will need another free-style job. Doesn't make much sense.

How do I go about doing this with one job? How do you guys achieve this? Using Pipeline? Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, you can manage this better with [Jenkins Pipeline](https://jenkins.io/solutions/pipeline/)

What you can do is the following :

1) Checkout the code from dev branch and put it in one directory in the workspace.

2) Compile and deploy from that directory.

3) Add a manual step for approval to deploy from master branch.

4) Repeat step 1 and 2.

A sample code would look something like this:

```
node {    
    // Get code from git repo
    checkout changelog: false, poll: false, scm: [$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: "origin/dev"]], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [[$class: 'RelativeTargetDirectory', relativeTargetDir: 'test-dev-dir']], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: '<jenkins-github-credential-id>', url: 'https://github.com/test']]]

      dir('test-dir') {
        // Do your stuff
        }

    // stage concurrency: 1, name: 'approve'
    // input id: 'master-deploy', message: 'Deploy from master?', ok: 'Deploy'

    // Get code from git repo
    checkout changelog: false, poll: false, scm: [$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: "origin/master"]], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [[$class: 'RelativeTargetDirectory', relativeTargetDir: 'test-master-dir']], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: '<jenkins-github-credential-id>', url: 'https://github.com/test']]]

    dir('test-master-dir') {
      // Preferbably create a tag for future hotfix maybe?
      // Do your stuff
      }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Manish. How do you push Dev code changes back to prod repo?

Comment: I believe this is a merge process so I would suggest to follow the current process of merging it manually because there could be potential conflicts which needs to be resolved manually. That's why I have added the manual approval process so that once some one has merged it, they can approve the deployment to prod.